# Make an image fly across the screen

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I'm making an image fly across the screen but I'd like this image to change every time the images get outs from the screen.

HTML:

```
<div class="flier">{image 1}</div>
```

To achieve this I've tried to change the HTML in something like this but I didn't get the result I wanted, instead I've got two images flying across the screen at the same time.

```
  <div class="flier">{image 1};{image 2}</div>
```

CSS:

```
.flier {
    pointer-events: none;
}

.flier > * {
/* Adjust animation duration to change the element’s speed */
        animation: fly 50s linear infinite;
        pointer-events: none !important;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translateX(-120%) translateY(-120%) rotateZ(0);
    position: fixed;
    animation-delay: 1s;
    z-index: 999999;
}

 /* Keyframe values control where the element will begin
    and end its trajectory across the screen. Each rule
    represents a path the element follows across the screen. */


@keyframes fly {

    98.001%, 0% {
                display: block;
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(100vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    15% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(-100%) rotateZ(180deg)
    }

    15.001%, 18% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(-30%) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    40% {
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(3vh) rotateZ(-180deg)
    }

    40.001%, 43% {
        transform: translateX(-200%) translateY(-100%) rotateZ(-180deg)
    }

    65% {
        transform: translateX(100vw) translateY(50vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }

    65.001%, 68% {
        transform: translateX(20vw) translateY(-200%) rotateZ(180deg)
    }

    95% {
        transform: translateX(10vw) translateY(100vh) rotateZ(0deg)
    }
}
```

Do you know a way to make those images fy across the screen but one by one? (when the first images gets out from the screen, the second image will start fly instead of the first)

Comment: Here is a very similar question. Animations are delayed(what you need :) ). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73159029/loop-with-vars-in-css/73159203

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you think it would be the best way to do that? plus when I use this in my HTML <div class="flier">{image 1};{image 2}</div> instead of just one image, the second image would follow the path of the first image! So It won't help me having it just delayed

Comment: If you have just 2 images, you can set the second one in reverse, so they won't look much like following the same path : example : `.flier img + img {
  animation-direction:reverse;
}`  https://jsfiddle.net/ack19mvx/  From here you will probably won't need a delay.